# Checking if div is visible and closing when click outside of it

Tags: javascript

Can somebody explain me how i can combine this two scripts in one? Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('.myContainer').is(':visible')) {
        alert('Hello');
    } 
});


$(document).mouseup(function(e) 
{
    var container = $(".myContainer");

    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Add `container.is(':visible') && ` at the start of the 2nd `if` conditional. Then remove the document.ready block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could combine the two chunks of code you have:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) 
  {
    var container = $(".myContainer");

    if (container.is(':visible') && !container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.hide();
    }
  });
});
```